# How do I grab the filename of the file containing a certain string when there are hundreds of files?

Tags: shell

I have a folder with 200 files in it.  We can say that the files are named "abc0" to "abc199".  Five of these files contain the string "ez123" but I don't know which ones.  My current attempt to find the file names of the files that contain the string is:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read FILES
do
cat $FILES | egrep "ez123"
done
```

I have a file that contains the filenames of all files in the directory.  So I then execute:

```
./script < filenames
```

This is verifies for me that the files containing the string exist but I still don't have the name of the files.  Are there any ideas concerning the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec fgrep -l 'ez123' \{\} \;
```

(`-maxdepth 1` is only necessary if you only want to search the directory and not the tree recursively (if there's any)).

`fgrep` is a bit faster than grep. `-l` lists the matched filenames only.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, that solved the issue and i was able to live happily ever after!

Answer (score 3):

you can try

```
grep -l "ez123" abc*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
find -type f -exec grep -qs "ez123" {} \; -print
```

This will use `find` to find all real files in current directory (and subdirectories), execute `grep` on them ({} will be replaced by file name, -qs tells it to be silent and just set an exit code), -print will print out the names of the files that grep found a matching line in.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
xargs egrep -l ez123
```

That reads filenames from stdin and prints out the filenames with matches.